# How do I move pixels and use physics on them in assembly

Tags: assembly

**Hello!**
I'm new with the assembly language and I need some help and it's related to flags and jumping... (jmp,cmp etc..)

---

My goal is to make moving objects on the graphic screen.
I have this code right here which is supposed to draw a red dot, and I don't know how to do the jumping in order to repeat it, for example whenever the row hits 319 it will turn the opposite, instead of adding 3 it will decrease 3 and the same goes for the column but I don't know how to make it work...
thanks alot for reading and hopefully you could help me :)

```
column1 = 0
row 1 = 0
 proc FirstObj
    ;top left corner object
    mov [row1],0
    mov [column1],0
    xor ax,ax
    xor cx,cx
    xor dx,dx
    xor al,al
        ;-----------------------
         MOV AH,0Ch
         MOV AL,[4]
         MOV CX,[row1] 
         MOV DX,[column1] 
         MOV AL,[0]
         MOV CX,[row1-3] 
         MOV DX,[column1-2] 
        ;-----------------------
    add [row1],3
    add [column1],2





    ret
    endp Firstobj
```

Comment: It seems you are hoping for someone to write the code for you. That's not how Stack Overflow works. You already seem to know that you should be using the comparison and conditional-branching instructions. The next step would be to look up those instructions in your favorite x86 instruction reference and see how they work. They aren't that complicated. `CMP` sets flags just like a subtraction, and most importantly, sets the zero flag (`ZF`) if the two values being compared are equal, so you can test and branch accordingly using either `JE` or `JNE`.

Comment: Aside from your actual question, the code you have is highly suspect. (1) You clear `AX` and then immediately clear `AL`. That's redundant, since `AL` is a part of `AX`. (2) It doesn't make sense to dereference a constant, as in `[4]`! (3) You carefully set up values in registers, and then turn around and load *new* values into those same registers, without ever doing anything with the original values. Perhaps you're missing an invoke of a BIOS or DOS interrupt that will generate the output? (4) And, just a final note, it's more efficient to load `AX` all at once, rather than `AL` then `AH`.